# php can't connect to o365 imap server after application migration

Tags: php, email, imap, o365-flow

I really tried to fix this by myself in the past 3 days but I run out of ideas.

The thing is that when I was testing the application on azure I didn't have any issues.
I already had a windows server `VM`, where I installed `WAMP` to test out the `PHP` app.
Everything was fine and working till I migrated the app to another hosting provider where I think they run Red Hat on the **`VM`**.

All ports are open for the IMAP and the PHP IMAP extension is enabled.

The thing is that I'm getting an error message when I try to connect to Server

```
name: outlook.office365.com
Port: 993
Encryption method: TLS/SSL (I tried both, but on the previous server was TLS)
```

**Can't connect to `FRA-efz.ms-acdc.office.com`,`993: Connection refused`**

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You can check if this is a firewall problem, by running (on a shell, on that server): `openssl s_client -connect outlook.office365.com:993 -showcerts`  I should show some certificate info. If the command fails, you probably have a firewall issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cant check this by myself because I don't have SSH open on the server. I pay them for management and they checked the ports only and the services. I will try to open SSH today and run a check by myself... just to be sure.

Comment: The problem was indeed at the firewall. Thank you for helping out :)